# How can I access values of other columns with v-slot:cell?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

With a b-table, I am using a template for a column. In this example, I have the column `id`. Here, I can get the value of `id` for the current row by using `data.value`. But within this template I also need the value from another column for this row. How can I get that?

```
<template v-slot:cell(id)="data">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slot-scope of table cells includes `value` and `item`. `item` being the data of the entire row.

```html
<template v-slot:cell(id)="{ value, item }">
 {{ value }} <-- value of this row, i.e. item.id
 {{ item.anotherKey }} <-- value of another row
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have access to `item` in the `props`. So in your case should be `data.item` and from the `item` you can get the other value.